# Issue with launching controller after creating admin user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently having an issue with my controller after creating an admin user. 
This is the code used to create the admin user:

```
  protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        using (var ac = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new 
            UserStore<ApplicationUser>(ac));
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new 
            RoleStore<IdentityRole>(ac));
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "hello@gmail.com", 
            Email = "hello@gmail.com" };
            userManager.Create(user, "Hello1234!");
            roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("admin"));

            user = userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName).Result;

            userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "admin");
        }
    }
```

**Updated due to mistake**

**When I navigate to the products controller I get this error in the browser:**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.PossiblyLoadTempData() +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__14(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +18
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +374
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +384
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +103
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2633.0
```

Comment: You need to call base.Initialize() to initialize the base Controller class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This method cannot be called directly. Override this method in order
>   to provide additional processing tasks before any ActionResult methods
>   are called, such as setting the thread culture or assigning a custom
>   provider for TempData objects. If you override this method, call the
>   base control's Initialize method.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);

    using (var ac  = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(ac));
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(ac));
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "hello@gmail.com", Email = "hello@gmail.com"};
        userManager.Create(user, "Hello1234!");
        roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("admin"));
        user = userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName).Result;
        userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "admin");
    }

}
```

Comment: Now it's breaking on userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "admin");

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: 'UserId not found.'

Comment: This is a different issue. Try searching for the issue first :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24389126/mvc5-usermanager-addtorole-error-adding-user-to-role-userid-not-found

Comment: @PJ.SQL That's because you didn't apply the code I provided in my answer to your previous question

Comment: So there is another question :D

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto my mistake. I posted the wrong code in this thread. However, I added base.Initialize(requestContext); to your code and it's working perfectly now!

Comment: I fixed both the question and this answer to reflect the correct code (so that this answer doesn't look weird)

Comment: I also fixed my original post